# Adding element to XML using javax parser without document modification

Tags: java, xml, parsing

i am trying to add elements to xml document. Elements are added successfuly but problem is, that parser modifies original xml file in other places e.g it swaps namespace and id attributes or deletes duplicate namespace definitions. I need to get precisely the same document (same syntax, preserved whitespaces) only with specific elements added. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Here is my code:

```
public void appendTimestamp(String timestamp, String signedXMLFile, String timestampedXMLFile){
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try{
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File(signedXMLFile));

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList list = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='Signature']/*[local-name()='Object']/*[local-name()='QualifyingProperties']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        if(list.getLength() != 1){
            throw new Exception();
        }

        Node node = list.item(0);
        Node unsignedProps = doc.createElement("xades:UnsignedProperties");
        Node unsignedSignatureProps = doc.createElement("xzep:UnsignedSignatureProperties");
        Node timestampNode = doc.createElement("xzep:SignatureTimeStamp");
        timestampNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(timestamp));

        unsignedSignatureProps.appendChild(timestampNode);
        unsignedProps.appendChild(unsignedSignatureProps);
        node.appendChild(unsignedProps);

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult stringWriter = new StreamResult(writer);
        transformer.transform(source, stringWriter);

        writer.flush();
        System.out.println(writer.toString());

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The original xml file:

```
...    
<ds:Object Id="objectIdVerificationObject" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
...
```

Modified xml file:

```
...
<ds:Object xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="objectIdVerificationObject">
...
```

Comment: As a quick and dirty fix (if this is urgent), consider modifying the final output of your code on a string level to swap over these attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the dom model, then the whole xml file is read, then represented in the memory as the node tree and then saved to xml in a way determined by the writer. So it is almost impossible to preserve the original xml format as you don't have the control over it and for example whitespaces are not represented at all in the node tree.

You need to read partially the original xml and ouptut its content to the new file preserving what was read, then in the "right" place you need to add your new content adn then continue simple coapying of the original.

For example you could use the `XMLStreamWriter` and `XMLStreamReader` to achieve that as they offer "the low" level operations.

But probably it would be much easier to just copy the xml as the text line by one till you recognize the insertion point, then create new xml portion and append it as text and continue with copying.

Comment: Thank you for response. I wanted to utilize xpath and convenient node manipulations so treating xml as text was my last option. So far i did not come across solution how to parse xml without parser modifing elements. Finally i did as you suggested and loaded xml into string then inserted xml portion in desired place.